# echoing a intval creates loads of whitespace

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a variable that is a long decimal (2.34353) and I want to round it to 2. So I am using intval on the variable. I then echo the intval and the value is correct, except that it spits out a bunch of whitespace before and after the value. In a var_dump it only shows the number, therefore (unless var_dump never shows whitespace) I am assuming echo'ing it is adding whitespace for some reason.

I tried a str_replace and preg_replace on the variable before the echo but the problem remains. I am developing on Wordpress, so I have a feeling it might be the culprit.

Any ideas on what to try next? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function

Answer (score 1):

```
echo trim(intval($myvar)); // should clear out any wrapping whitespace
```

Comment: Tried it, but the whitespace remains!

Answer (score 0):

1. Intval is not a rounding function. It just drops the fractional part of a number. Use [round](http://php.net/round) for rounding.
2. There is no problem with echo or with intval. Probletm is out there. Try to echo empty string `echo '';`, and to look what you get.